# Javascript pushing unknown name function into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to make a news system.
I have a table where each element is a function producing text.

I have a loop that checks whether news+number is a function or undefined.
If it is a function, then I push news+number to the array [number].

I am using eval, because i don't know any other way to push the function name and the number to the array.

CODE:

```
var tablicaNewsow = [news1,news2]

function addNews ()
{
  var counterArray = 0;
  var fName = " ";
  fName = "news1";
  while (eval('typeof' + " " + fName) == "function")
  {
    //---------------sprawdzenie czy news istnieje----------
    fName = "news" + (counterArray+1);
    if (eval('typeof' + " " + fName) == "function")
    {
      //------------jest news
      tablicaNewsow.push(eval(fName+"()"));
      }
    else
    {
      //-----------nie ma newsa
      }
    counterArray++;
  }
}
```

NOTE:This is a code segment from my system, which pushes functions in the array.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do what you want in other ways,  if you can't skip the `eval` thing, you should probably think again why do you even need it!

Comment: Please don't eval! You can use an object and set a key using "array-like" notation: obj[key]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `window["news"+number]` (or similar). Any global variable can be accessed in this way.

Otherwise you could just use an array instead of indexing multiple variable names.

Answer (score 0):

this is a code example that expects the functions to be global:

```
function addNews ()
{
    var counterArray = 0;
    var f = window["news1"];
    while (typeof f == "function")
    {
        //---------------sprawdzenie czy news istnieje----------
        f = window["news" + (counterArray+1)];
        if (typeof f == "function")
        {
            //------------jest news
            tablicaNewsow.push(f);
        }
        counterArray++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a function name in the current scope using *this*:

```
if (typeof(this[fName]) == 'function') {
  this[fName]();
}
```

Or, if you're inside an object, but you know the functions live in the global scope, you can use *window*:

```
if (typeof(window[fName]) == 'function') {
  window[fName]();
}
```

Of course, **if** the the above snippet runs in the global/window scope -- or even in a **function** that lives in the global/window scope, this == window, and either option will work.